# Outlook 2011, Where are the mails stored?

Tags: macbook-pro, email, ms-office

Just as the mails in Outlook under windows are stored in a PST file , where are the mails in Outlook under Mac stored ?

I understand they are stored as OLM files . But can anyone tell me the exact location of these files so i can perform a backup ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to Microsoft's [support site](http://www.microsoft.com/mac/support):

> Outlook stores only the indices in the Database (with a capital “D”) file and stores the data records as a series of files nested within folders. The Database file and its folders are located here:

```
~/Documents/Microsoft User Data/Office 2011 Identities/Main Identity/Database
~/Documents/Microsoft User Data/Office 2011 Identities/Main Identity/Data Records
```